# Codeigniter save HTML data, issue with Entities

Tags: php, html, database, codeigniter, entities

I use codeignitier and I would like to save some html code (templates) into the DB.

the problem is that I got every time the entities saved into the DB.
I've this &lt ; instead of <

In my lib I put

```
$this->ci->form_validation->set_rules('html_text', 'HTML text', 'htmlspecialchars');
```

and

```
$html_text   = $this->ci->input->post('html_text',true);
```

in my view I use a textarea and CKeditor

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you post the text field the contents are ASCII encoded for transit. Which is what you are seeing in the data. 
De-encode on the server before storing to data, or else dencode on the client side after retrieving. I would recommend doing these things on the server as you need to prevent XSS and SQL injection (because what you are doing can be very dangerous). Use a validation library.